# How to put regular "post to facebook" tasks in MS-Project?

Tags: ms-project

I'm new to project management, among other tasks our company has decided to post messages to social media regularly. Say we want to post every week, how would you write these tasks in MS-Project?

```
Post to Facebook 
 - write
 - design graphics
 - post
 - analyze
```

It is more like a 'to do list'. How do I just write this group of tasks as recurring task (say every Monday)? And is this the best way to do this?

[image: A group of tasks (no recurring)]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could very well decompose the activities that your team will be performing prior posting the details to Social Media. These would be your tasks to perform. You will need to set the tasks as recurring task.

The details about how to set a task as recurring is available [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-recurring-tasks-88a4d903-38c3-4665-870e-4810b752f2c4).

Hope this helps